# Minicom not connecting to cisco over usb / serial

Tags: linux, debian, remote-access

We have configured a Pi to be a recovery device, OOB access for a core router.  It connects to a Cisco serial over a FTDI USB Serial Device converter

```
root@hex-pi:~# dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=592 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=448 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa01041 bcm2709.serial=0x22a9fa3c smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:A9:FA:3C bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.disk_led_gpio=47 bcm2709.disk_led_active_low=0 sdhci-bcm2708.emmc_clock_freq=250000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p6 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
[    0.001770] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.748325] dev:f1: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 83, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev3
[    1.266642] console [ttyAMA0] enabled
[    4.438734] usb 1-1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I originally configured and tested this access locally to another device before and it worked fine.  Now it's live in a remote DC (of course) it doesn't work.

Intrestingly:

```
root@hex-pi:~# cat /etc/minicom/minirc.dfl
# Machine-generated file - use "minicom -s" to change parameters.
pu port             /dev/ttyUSB0
pu baudrate         9600
pu rtscts           Yes
```

Shows USB0 as default.  However when using # minicom on the cli i get the following error:

```
root@hex-pi:~# minicom
minicom: cannot open /dev/ttyUSB1: No such file or directory
```

I believe my config is correct ...

```
root@hex-pi:~# minicom -s

 A -    Serial Device      : /dev/ttyUSB1                              |
    | B - Lockfile Location     : /var/lock                                 |
    | C -   Callin Program      :                                           |
    | D -  Callout Program      :                                           |
    | E -    Bps/Par/Bits       : 9600 8N1                                  |
    | F - Hardware Flow Control : Yes                                       |
    | G - Software Flow Control : No
```

However ... USB1 is persistant, although I change it to USB0, save as dfl and try again it still comes back as USB1.

Now I have tried using the following:

```
minicom --device /dev/ttyUSB0
```

And I just get an empty prompt as follows:

```
Welcome to minicom 2.6.1

OPTIONS: I18n
Compiled on Apr 28 2012, 19:24:31.
Port /dev/ttyUSB0

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

I have tried perms and still no help

```
root@hex-pi:/dev# chmod 777 ttyUSB0
root@hex-pi:/dev# ls -la | grep USB
crwxrwxrwx  1 root dialout 188,   0 May 14 09:43 ttyUSB0
```

The only other thing i have noticed at the bottom of minicom is the following

```
CTRL-A Z for help |  9600 8N1 | NOR | Minicom 2.6.1  | VT102 |      Offline
```

Pretty out of ideas now, anyone know what may be wrong or what could be the issue?  I can not install screen as this device doesn't have internet access outside VPN.  So no attitude.

Comment: Did you tap Enter a couple of times? Is the cable actually connected?

Comment: Indeed it is.  Tried connecting a few times mashing that enter button to get a console up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the serial cable being used was duff.  Replaced and now working as should be.